# Python: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error.  I've check the path for student and grade and they print out fine.  I'm trying to drop any values of current students who have grades listed as fail.  Any suggestions on how to improve this code?

```
df.drop(df.query(student == 'current' and grade == 'fail').index, inplace=True)
```

This is the full error I get:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Python 3

Comment: can we see a sample of yout dataset??

Comment: user_id dt student grade
    0 851304 11:48.6 current fail
    1 806248 01:45.2 current fail
    2 861590 55:06.2 not current pass
    3 853451 28:03.1 not current pass
    4 864925 52:26.2 current pass

Comment: Please _paste_ your _formatted_ data into the question.

Comment: sorry not sure of a good way to show you
It's a basic table.  user_id, dt, student, grade are the columns

Comment: For starters, there must be quotation marks around `"student == 'current' and grade == 'fail'"`.

Comment: my fault...I had already made variables for these earlier in the code block.

student = df['student']
grade = df['grade']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
import operator
df.drop((df.loc[operator.and_(df.student == 'current', df.grade == 'fail')]).index, inplace=True)
```